# Git Merge Conflict - Remote File Deleted, Local File Changed

Tags: git, git-merge, git-merge-conflict

I merged in changes from another branch but I am getting conflicts because a file has been deleted on the remote branch but has changes on local branch.

I would like to delete the file - I tried `git rm path/to/file` but it says `file: needs merge`. What is the best way of removing the file and committing the merge?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try using the `--force` parameter:

```
git rm --force <file>
```

If you want to keep the file in filesystem:

```
git rm --cached <file>
```

Comment: got the same problem, but `--force` doesnt work, it still says "needs merge" for the file(s)

Comment: It is working, but isn't there is a way to do it for all files deleted?

Comment: Of course. You can use `git diff --diff-filter=D --name-only -z | xargs -0 git rm --force --cached`

Comment: @AndrewBullock  it says that, but it still deletes the file. It's diagnostics, which some may consider to be a bit excessive.

Comment: @NavaPolakOnik er. Make it `git diff --diff-filter=D --name-only -z HEAD..MERGE_HEAD | xargs -0 git rm --force --cached`

Comment: This would be a much better answer it you explained the command you're using!

Answer (score 7):

> I tried `git rm path/to/file` but it says file: `needs merge`

You will no longer see that error message with Git 2.23 (Q3 0219, seven years later)

"`git rm`" resolving a conflicted path used to leak an internal message
"`needs merge`" before actually removing the path, which was confusing.
This has been corrected.

See [commit b2b1f61](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b2b1f615ce3b9383a32dec7f84488284004224f3) (17 Jul 2019) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 5e9d978](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5e9d9787d278331385dbfcf962b32dc4e8d3eb5e), 25 Jul 2019)</sup>

> ### rm: resolving by removal is not a warning-worthy event
>
> When resolving a conflict on a path in favor of removing it, using
>   "`git rm`" on it is the standard way to do so.
>   The user however is greeted with a "`needs merge`" message during that operation:
>
> ```
> $ git merge side-branch
> $ edit conflicted-path-1
> $ git add conflicted-path-1
> $ git rm conflicted-path-2
> conflicted-path-2: needs merge
> rm 'conflicted-path-2'
> ```
>
> The removal by "`git rm`" does get performed, but an uninitiated user
>   may find it confusing:
>   "`needs merge`? So I need to resolve conflict
>   before being able to remove it???"
>
> The message is coming from "[`update-index --refresh`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index#Documentation/git-update-index.txt---refresh)" that is called
>   internally to make sure "`git rm`" knows which paths are clean and
>   which paths are dirty, in order to prevent removal of paths modified
>   relative to the index without the "`-f`" option.
>
> We somehow ended up not squelching this message which seeped through to the UI surface.
>
> Use the same mechanism used by "`git commit`", "`git describe`", etc. to
>   squelch the message.